# Can somebody explain whats happening in my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So i've got some ajax calls happening. The first getJson one returns an json object which i name "tables" its structured as tables['tables'] lists the name of tables in a database. key1 represents each table name. So i specifically loop through each table. I'm testing stuff out so when the table name is specifically "interfaces" (see if statements) then i want to execute another ajax request to retrieve the data from that table itself.

Its weird because the console.log(key1) does spit out if key1 == "Intefaces", however, my second console.log(key1) doesnt spit out on interfaces. It spits out on "vlan" which is the last table in my database.

Despite this my items array fills with the correct data from interfaces.

I dont understand why once i get into my second getJson statement, the val of key1 changes, especially when that function shouldnt even be accessible when key1 doesnt equal "Interfaces".

```
$.getJSON( "/ryan/nonEmber/getTables.php", function( data ) {
        tables = data;    
        for (var key1 in tables['tables']) {
              if (tables['tables'].hasOwnProperty(key1)) {
                console.log(key1 + " -> " + tables['tables'][key1]);
                if(key1 == 'Interfaces'){
                    console.log(key1);
                    $.getJSON("/ryan/nonEmber/getJson.php?table=" + key1, function( data2 ){
                        var items = [];
                        $.each(data2.post, function(key, val){
                              items.push(val);
                        });
                        console.log(key1);
                        for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
                            var myString = '<tr id = "visibleRow">';
                            for(j = 0; j < tables['tables'][key1].length; j++){
                                myString = myString + '<td id = "visibleDef">' + items[i][tables['tables'][key1][j]] +'</td>';
                                }
                            myString = myString + '</tr>';
                            Interfaces.push(myString);
                        }
                    }); 
                }
              }
        }
});
```

You'll probably my problem lies in my ajax. Which it probably is, but i've written ajax functions that depend on other ajax functions in the past and they've worked correctly. In fact, this function that i showed here was replacing another one that invovled 3 ajax calls. I just was trying to shorten it.

Can anybody explain whats happening here?

Comment: My first suggestion so you dont have this messy ass code is to isolate the functionality and put them into functions. FOR THE LOVE OF MAINTANANCE! :) This would also lend itself to using promises eventually which would make sure data is resolved similar to how it done in these anonymous callback functions

Comment: So what, you're saying have my first getJson call, and then call a seperate written function from within the anonymous function?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should for the most part try to created named functions in general. I'm not sure if im understanding your code completely but to me it would seems like you could totally get rid of the 2nd ajax call but I dont understand completely what is happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous.

Your loop triggers the Ajax request.

The function you pass to `getJSON` is an **event handler** that runs *when the HTTP response is received*.

None of the responses are received until the loop that repeatedly calls `getJSON` is finished, by which time the value is the last one.

See [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](/questions/6487366/how-to-generate-event-handlers-with-loop-in-javascript) for the work around.

Comment: Sorry this is confusing me. If i use event handlers in the loop, i'm writing an event handler to call the next ajax call??

Comment: You are already using event handlers. The function you pass to `getJSON` is an event handler. You are assigning them in a loop. You have a call to `getJSON` inside a loop. This is your problem (which is the same as the one in the linked question).

Comment: Ah okay, thank you :) I was worried that due to the nature of ajax i wouldnt be able to do this at all. Thanks for the help, this worked.